# Return Field Based on Condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to return a specific email type based on student type. If a student is a type 'YC', then return the mail address that is coded as 'Yale'.  If student type is SU, then return email address coded as 'HAPP'.

The student type field is SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_COLL_CODE_1 Coll_Code.
The email type is GOREMAL.GOREMAL_Emal_Code.

How can I do this?

Thank you

```sql
select distinct
             SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_ID as SID, 
             SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_COLL_CODE_1 Coll_Code,
             SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME as LNAME,
             SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME as FNAME,
             SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_PTRM_CODE PoT,
             SSBSECT.SSBSECT_PTRM_START_DATE Session_Start, 
             SSBSECT.SSBSECT_PTRM_END_DATE Session_End,
              SLRRASG.SLRRASG_ASCD_CODE Housing,
              sum(tbraccd.tbraccd_balance) Balance,
              goremal.goremal_email_address Email
--              listagg( distinct goremal.goremal_email_address, ',') within group (order by goremal.goremal_email_address) as Emails
--              
            from 
              SATURN.SFRSTCR
              join SATURN.SGBSTDN
               on SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_PIDM = SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_PIDM
                 and SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_TERM_CODE_EFF = SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE
              join SATURN.SPRIDEN
                on SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_PIDM = SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_PIDM
               join SATURN.SSBSECT
              on SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = SSBSECT.SSBSECT_TERM_CODE
                and SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_CRN = SSBSECT.SSBSECT_CRN
              join TAISMGR.TBRACCD
                on SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_PIDM = TAISMGR.TBRACCD.TBRACCD_PIDM
                 --and SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_TERM_CODE_EFF = TAISMGR.TBRACCD.TBRACCD_TERM_CODE
             left join general.goremal
                on SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_PIDM = "GENERAL".GOREMAL.GOREMAL_PIDM
                      and GOREMAL.GOREMAL_Emal_Code  in ('YALE', 'HAPP')
              left join SATURN.SLRRASG
              on SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_PIDM = SLRRASG.SLRRASG_PIDM
                 and SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_TERM_CODE_EFF = SLRRASG.SLRRASG_TERM_CODE
                 and  SLRRASG_BEGIN_DATE > '01-July-2023'
             
            where 
                
                SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_TERM_CODE_EFF = '202302' 
               and TAISMGR.TBRACCD.TBRACCD_TERM_CODE = '202302'
               --and SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_PTRM_CODE = 'H8'
              --and SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_PTRM_CODE in ('H10', 'H4B', 'H5A', 'H5B', 'HE3', 'H6','HND','HYW')
              and SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_PTRM_CODE in ('H4B', 'HE3', 'HND', 'H5B')
                and SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_RSTS_CODE in ('RE', 'RW')
               -- and SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_COLL_CODE_1 = 'SU'
               
                --and SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_ID = '925858581'
                and SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_CHANGE_IND is null 
           
              and ( SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_COLL_CODE_1 = 'YC' and goremal.goremal_email_address in ('Yale') or SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_COLL_CODE_1 = 'SU' and goremal.goremal_email_address in ('HAPP') )
                 
            group by
              goremal.goremal_email_address,
               SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_CRN,
               SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_ID,
              SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME, 
              SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME,
              SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_PTRM_CODE,
              SSBSECT.SSBSECT_PTRM_START_DATE, 
             SSBSECT.SSBSECT_PTRM_END_DATE,
               SLRRASG.SLRRASG_ASCD_CODE,
             SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_COLL_CODE_1
             
            order by SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME
```

Comment: A [mcve] would make this much clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include these conditions when you join the email table (`GENERAL.GOREMAL`) to ensure you get the correct email from that table:

```sql
LEFT JOIN GENERAL.GOREMAL
ON SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_PIDM = GENERAL.GOREMAL.GOREMAL_PIDM
AND (
   (SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_COLL_CODE_1 = 'YC'
   AND GOREMAL.GOREMAL_EMAL_CODE = 'Yale')
 OR 
   (SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_COLL_CODE_1 = 'SU'
   AND GOREMAL.GOREMAL_EMAL_CODE = 'HAPP')
)
```

Comment: In general it's better to use regular AND/OR constructions instead of case _expressions_ in the WHERE clause.